# 32bit Dll wrapper for native 64bit dll

Tags: c#, c++, dll, interop, wrapper

I have created a 64 bit dll using c++. Is it possible to have a c# 32bit dll as a wrapper to above 64bit dll?

I was able to get done work by creating a 64bit c# wrapper dll. But when I tried to have 32bit wrapper it doesn't work, Is it possible? or am I doing something never can be done?

Answer (score 4):

32-bit code can't (directly) call 64-bit code, and vice versa. You have to transition modes, which can really only be done at OS-level. So although I'm not an expert on .Net/C#, I'd say "not possible".

You could build a standalone service process that runs in a 64-bit space and uses the 64-bit DLL, and use interprocess communication to pass data back and forth.

Or compile the DLL as a 32-bit library...

Comment: Absolutely correct: A 32-bit process can never load a 64-bit DLL. Interop (with application-specific DLLs) with AnyCPU assemblies presents yet another challenge. :)